# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre chupetear y chupar?

Tags: verbos, sufijos, diferencias-entre-palabras

¿Qué diferencia hay entre las palabras **chupetear** y **chupar**?

He visto gente hablando de las dos formas y todavía no entiendo qué diferencias hay o en cuál contexto podemos utilizarlas.

Me gustaría saber si hay contextos en los cuáles solo se puede utilizar una o la otra palabra.

Por lo que he visto en los diccionarios, parece que el significado es prácticamente el mismo.

Comment: ¿Qué definiciones has visto?

Comment: Chupetear: Chupar de forma reiterada
Chupar: Sacar o traer com los labios y la lengua;

Por la forma que ya vi las personas hablando me parecen que usan com el mismo significado;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Chupetear* es una derivación **iterativa** (o **frecuentativa**) de *chupar*. Es decir que marca una acción repetida. El sufijo *-ear* tiene ese significado, [entre muchos otros](http://www.sufijos.lli.ulaval.ca/corpus-1/contenido/formas-sufijales-en-e/sufijo-no-traslat-e-ar/) (suele aparecer como *-tear* o *-quear*). Otros pares de verbos que siguen este patrón son

- *pisar ~ pisotear*
- *besar ~ besuquear*
- *correr ~ corretear*
- *parlar ~ parlotear* (*parlar* con su significado original de *hablar*)
- *temblar ~ temblequear*

No son verbos intercambiables. Los verbos iterativos como éstos suelen ser creaciones espontáneas de los hablantes. Muchas veces son más bien informales, expresivos o pintorescos, y pueden incluso sonar vulgares. Por ejemplo, se puede decir

> *Las mariposas chupan el néctar de las flores para alimentarse.*

pero no se puede decir *«Las mariposas chupetean...»*, aun cuando la definición del diccionario lo permita, porque *chupetear* no sólo implica repetición. *Chupar* es emocionalmente y estéticamente neutro; *chupetear* indica una acción expresiva, quizá excesiva o grotesca.

Answer (score 0):

Chupetear implica repetición de chupar, como pisotear respecto de pisar, picotear respecto de picar, etc.

Si necesitas más info, luego amplío.

Comment: Nunca habá visto esta definición. Ya habá visto definiciones similares como picotazo o puñetazo, pero nunca me habá dado cuenta que serían actos de repetición, pensaba que era el nombre no más.

Answer (score -1):

Chupetear es un verbo y es la acción de usar un chupete, chupeta o chupón.

Chupar es otro verbo que es sinonimo de succionar o mamar.